# Motorola Droid 4 synonym

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

We have an extraneous tag ([droid4](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/droid4)) that should be synonymized to [motorola-droid-4](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-droid-4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merged and synonymized. Thanks.